# move files between directories in single GCP bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set up cloud functions to move files between folders inside one bucket in GCP.

Whenever the user loads files into the provided bucket folder, my cloud functions move the file to another folder where big data scripts are looking after.

It shows successful while setting up, however, files are not moving from the source folders.

[image]

Appreciate your help

```
from google.cloud import storage

def move_file(bucket_name, bucket_Folder, blob_name):
    """Moves a blob from one folder to another with the same name."""
    bucket_name = 'bucketname'
    blob_name = 'filename'

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = bucket.blob("Folder1/" + blob_name)
    new_blob = bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, bucket, "Folder2/" + blob_name)
    blob.delete()

    print('Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} .'.format(source_blob.name, bucket.name, new_blob.name))
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function from? Please include that code as well.

Comment: The tag [batch-file] description is _A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on MS-DOS, IBM OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems_.

Comment: @DustinIngram created a cloud function with the above py scripts. so I am calling this function from it.

Comment: are you using default service account or custom service account, check permission details

Comment: I am using custom service account which has proper permissions as my other cloud functions are working proper. I guess it is something to do with the py scripts in calling folders inside bucket. Also, There are no errors in stakedrive logs as well.

Comment: @VickyKrish Please show us the Cloud Function as well, which is calling this function.

Comment: updated cloud function screenprint https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtSpO.png

Comment: How many files do you have?

Comment: For now, I am expecting one file(*.CSV File) gets uploaded at a time. But trying to build the scripts which could handle 'n' of files to move from Upload folder to another folder in the same bucket one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you provided, the variable `blob` is not defined anywhere, so the source file won't be deleted. Instead of `blob.delete()`, change that line to `source_blob.delete()`.

Also, I assume you are aware that you're ["moving"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) just a single file. If you want to move all files prefixed with `Folder1/` to `Folder2` you could do something like this instead:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def move_files(self):

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucketname')
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='Folder1/')

    for blob in blobs:
     bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_name=blob.name.replace('Folder1/', 'Folder2/'))
```

For the latter, I reckon that there could be more efficient or better ways to do it.

Comment: Great, Thank you for the suggestions. I am trying to move files from the Folder1 to folder2  as in when files comes in. BTW, Changing into source_blob.delete() did not work. However the replace command works.

Comment: Hi @Vicky Krish, if the answer of Maxim worked for you, please accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just moving the object inside of the same bucket you can just [rename the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#rename) with the desired route.

In Google Cloud Platform Storage there are no folders, just the illusion of them. Everything after the name of the bucket is part of the name of the object.

Also, I can see many errors in your function. You can use this generic function to move a blob from one folder to another inside of the same bucket:

from google.cloud import storage
def rename_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, new_name):
    """Renames a blob."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # blob_name = "folder/myobject"
    # new_name = "newfolder/myobject"

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

new_blob = bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_name)

print("Blob {} has been renamed to {}".format(blob.name, new_blob.name))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with rename. However I intended to keep the folders there so I can move files from Folder1 to Folder2 whenever new files gets uploaded.

Comment: You can read this document about [How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) I find it helpfull to work with Google Cloud Storage. In this case even if you rename the last file of a folder and the folder gets empty it wont be deleted, I just did a test and the folder remains empty so with this method you are good to go

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I ran this one and it error-ed with below one,

Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
rename_blob() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_name'

Comment: that error means that you missed one argument. In this lane: new_blob = bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_name) you have to replace the value 'new_name' with the new folder/name of your object 'newfolder/samename.csv' or 'newfolder/anotherfolder/newname.csv'

Comment: Well, I did the same and it is giving out the same error. weird!

Comment: can you please share with us a snippet of your code and the error?